# Trying to pull dataframe from html table, however when I run df.info, error occurs (AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'info')

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

Excerpt from code below:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

souptable = soup.find(text='header').findParent('table')

df = pd.read_html(str(souptable))

df.info
```

I am just starting out with python.

First I am using BeautifulSoup to pull information from a webpage. Then I look for a specific column name 'header' and locate the whole table with findParent('table') as this table does not have an id. Then I convert to a pandas dataframe using read_html.

I have tried many other commands such as df.iloc, df.drop, and others as I am looking to rename column headers as my next step, however I always receive the error below. The "info" changes based on whatever function I attempt to use.

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'info'

Comment: **Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].** What do/don't you understand from the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, according to the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html):

> Returns:
>   dfs : list of DataFrames

When you run `pd.read_html`, it returns a *list* of dataframes. Just loop through each one and print the info out for each:

```
df_list = pd.read_html(str(souptable))
for df in df_list:
    print(df.info)
```